# How to wrap text around image in nested container

Tags: html, css

I want to wrap the text around image while the image stays on the top right.

I've tried changing a few things but couldn't make it work. The text is still working like block elements. How to make it wrap around the image?

Note: *The markup shouldn't be changed*.

```css
.text-container {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.img-container {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
.img-container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="text-container">
                <div class="text-container-wrapper">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Ex deleniti voluptates placeat? Assumenda, magni
                        maiores.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Eveniet sunt cupiditate earum iusto, quam excepturi sint
                        veniam ea rerum alias blanditiis repellendus.
                        Voluptatum?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Nulla voluptatibus possimus amet quas, ut tempore
                        inventore qui quis sequi reprehenderit repellendus
                        veniam porro?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Suscipit beatae rem voluptates dolores. Iste dignissimos
                        exercitationem dolorum placeat necessitatibus
                        accusantium quod neque commodi.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Laboriosam, quidem nostrum! Quis consectetur dolor
                        laudantium animi, similique consequuntur minus ab.
                        Fugiat, ipsam ullam.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img-container">
                <div class="img-container-wrapper">
                    <img
                        src="https://basava.codelinden.com/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/images/placeholder.png"
                        alt=""
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You have the text in the first column floated left and the image in the second column floated right. Of course the text is not going to go outside of its own container.

Answer (score 0):

***if*** moving element is possible, there's a solution: move your image div *inside* the text div and it'll wrap the image. CSS stays the same. The content of a div can't "jump" into another div to wrap its content. They have to be at the same level.

```css
.text-container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.img-container {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
.img-container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="text-container">
                <div class="text-container-wrapper"><div class="img-container">
                <div class="img-container-wrapper">
                    <img
                        src="https://basava.codelinden.com/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/images/placeholder.png"
                        alt=""
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Ex deleniti voluptates placeat? Assumenda, magni
                        maiores.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Eveniet sunt cupiditate earum iusto, quam excepturi sint
                        veniam ea rerum alias blanditiis repellendus.
                        Voluptatum?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Nulla voluptatibus possimus amet quas, ut tempore
                        inventore qui quis sequi reprehenderit repellendus
                        veniam porro?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Suscipit beatae rem voluptates dolores. Iste dignissimos
                        exercitationem dolorum placeat necessitatibus
                        accusantium quod neque commodi.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Laboriosam, quidem nostrum! Quis consectetur dolor
                        laudantium animi, similique consequuntur minus ab.
                        Fugiat, ipsam ullam.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank  you for your answer. But the elements can't be moved. Is there any way to achieve this without changing the markup?

Comment: As the 2 divs are independent, I don't think so...

Comment: The content of a div can't "*jump*" into another div to wrap its content. They have to be at the same level.